# Ubuntu with ENA installed doesn't boot on C5 instance type

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (CIS benchmark image, but I don't think it's related).
I installed ENA according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#test-enhanced-networking-ena.
I imaged and relaunched my AMI as m4.x16large and I do have ENA active:

```
ethtool -i eth0
driver: ena
version: 1.5.0g
```

I ran update-initramfs (tried both '-u' and '-c'), created AMI, and tried to launch as c5.4xlarge.
boot fails with:

```
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... /scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 24: dirname: not found

done.

Gave up waiting for root device. 
......
```

Any ideas?
TIA, Vitaly